# What could be the ways to handle user features based on subscription tiers in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I was thinking about ways to handle nicely parts/pages/features of a Blazor WebApp based on which subscription tiers a user belongs.

First that came in mind is the native use of `<AuthorizeView>` with `Roles` as the main distinguiscer(so other than the normal `"user"` role it could be concatenated with `"professional"`, `"business"` or `"enterprise"`.

But I was wondering: is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use the newer, and recommended, policy-based authorization with Blazor. Role-based authorization had been popular in Asp.Net, and it is becoming obsolete. It is enabled in .NET Core mainly because of compatibility reasons. But even Role-based authorization, in .NET Core, is implemented via claims.

The way to go is policy-based authorization. It is much easier to manage than Role-based authorization... and you can easily integrate it with the `AuthorizeView` component and the Authorize attribute. There are other issues with the Role-based authorization, which is demanding and requires you to write code, as for instance, Blazor expects to get a list of roles as in the following: Authorize[Roles="role1, role2, role3"], while identity server sends a single claim which is made of three roles. Consequently, you'll need to extract the roles and provide it to Blazor in the form of a list. This requires lots of work, and knowledge. OK..., I won't confuse you any further. Just forget about roles.

Comment: Okay, I'll +1 that.  A Role is one of many kinds of claims, so actually EVEN IF you use Role-based authorization, you are only going to be adding further functionality by thinking in terms of Claims.  Here's a video about the difference that I enjoyed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uw2ujXvN3i4

Comment: When you would like to add a policy as a claim, the `key` is the policy name meanwhile the `value` what's supposed to be?

Comment: A policy is not a claim... Search for policy-based authorization in the docs, and if you encounter some issues, don't hesitate to ask more specific questions.

Comment: I tried to follow this tutorial https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-configuring-policy-based-authorization-with-blazor/ without success, I have a 403 forbidden on the WebAPI calls and can't figure out how it does happen, do you have a better guide that's based on JWT and no Identity*?

Comment: Excuse me, but I'm done with this question... Please form new questions, provide the code you have, and you may even upload a complete repo of your app. The tutorials by   @Chris Sainty are excellent, and he provides complete code samples...no better guide. Don't use it with WebApi right now.  Try to understand the concept, and then go ahead with WebApi. Note: This week I've answered a series of questions about policy-based authorization, Web Api, and more by a user named NoviceCoder. They contain lots of code, and they may be of much help to you...Sorry, but I'm done with this question

Comment: I think I figure it out, took completely out of equation the `Roles` and it's working great

Answer (score 1):

I would 100% use roles.  You can give a person multiple roles, so you could do tiers, or even component-membership: "Unlock X page, unlock Y feature"